# inline pointer variable multiple definition

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

This is a question about inline variables and their uniqueness across multiple translation units. Consider the following code which shares a string literal across two translation units:

File hdr.h:

```
inline const char* const str = "hello world";
```

File tu0.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "hdr.h"

void foo()
{
  printf("tu0: &str=%p, str=%p\n", &str, str);
}
```

File tu1.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "hdr.h"

extern void foo();

int main()
{
  foo();
  printf("tu1: &str=%p str=%p\n", &str, str);
}
```

For completeness, here is how I compile these (on linux, 64-bit, binutils 2.28):

```
$ CXX -c -std=c++1z tu0.cpp -o tu0.o
$ CXX -c -std=c++1z tu1.cpp -o tu1.o
$ CXX -std=c++1z tu*.o -o a.out
```

With CXX=clang-4.0, both str and &str are identical:

```
tu0: &str=0x400608 str=0x4005f9
tu1: &str=0x400608 str=0x4005f9
```

But with g++ version 7.1 and 7.2, I get the surprising result:

```
tu0: &str=0x4005d8 str=0x4005b4
tu1: &str=0x4005d8 str=0x4005e0
```

Ok, I actually have more than one question (but they are all related):

1. Should str and &str have the same value in all translation units?
2. N4687 [dcl.inline]/6 says an inline variable should have the *same definition* in every translation unit. Does 'definition' refer to the source token "hello world" or to the pointer value of the string literal "hello world"?
3. How does GCC manage to get the same address for str, but different values depending on where the variable is accessed? And this leads to the last question:
4. Do inline variables require more run-time overhead (upon each access) than the usual approach of extern declarations with manual definition in a single translation unit?

Comment: Try to compile with `g++ -O1 -S -fverbose-asm tu0.cpp` then look into the generated assembler file `tu0.s`. I suspect you should want to enable optimization (with `-O1`).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, indeed that makes the values equal! So it this a bug in gcc? Is my understanding of how it's supposed to work correct?

Comment: Not a bug, but inlining is an optimization (and `inline` keyword is mostly a *hint* to the compiler). See also `--gc-sections` option to `ld` linker. BTW, your question is implementation (compiler and operating system) specific.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, if you look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline point 3, subpoint 2 under Description, it says that an inline variable has a single unique address. Second, I thought it given that two symbols of the same type with the same global address had to have identical values. Is my latter assumption wrong?

Comment: Don't you mean `inline const char str[]="hello world";` ??? BTW you might ask on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure. I'm trying to parse N4687 6.2 para 6 to see why my version should not work, but it's not clear to me. Incidentally the n4424 (the inline variable paper) uses a constexpr const char* kFoo = "foo bar"  example, so I'd love to learn why my version is wrong.

Comment: I can't think of a rule that permits GCC's behavior here. In all likelihood it simply propagated the constant value when translating the TUs.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I thought inlining for inline variables was required, and that it was only a hint for functions, which would make it not implementation specific.